# Have a centered label fill the whole parent div

Tags: html, jquery, css, checkbox, centering

I am using labels to check/uncheck hidden checkboxes. I need to be able to click anywhere within the div AND for the label to be centered within that same div.

Here is my html :

```html
<div id="syllabe" class="container">
  <div id="syllabe-1" class="syllabe-container"><label for="toggle-syllabe-1">1</label></div>
  <div id="syllabe-2" class="syllabe-container"><label for="toggle-syllabe-2">2</label></div>
  <div id="syllabe-3" class="syllabe-container"><label for="toggle-syllabe-3">3</label></div>
  <div id="syllabe-4" class="syllabe-container"><label for="toggle-syllabe-4">4</label></div>
  <div id="syllabe-5" class="syllabe-container"><label for="toggle-syllabe-5">5</label></div>
</div>
<div id="syllabe2" class="container">
  blabla2
</div>
<div id="syllabe3" class="container">
  blabla3
</div>
<div id="syllabe4" class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-syllabe-1" onclick="toggle(this)">
</div>
```

CSS :

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

#syllabe {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.syllabe-container {
  font-size: xx-large;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.syllabe-container-selected {
  font-size: xx-large;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#syllabe3 {
  height: 200px;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

and JS (using JQuery) :

```js
let toggle = (checkbox) => {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    $("#syllabe-1").removeClass("syllabe-container").addClass("syllabe-container-selected")
  } else {
    $("#syllabe-1").removeClass("syllabe-container-selected").addClass("syllabe-container")
  }
}
$(function() {

})
```

And the result :
[image]

And after clicking exactly on the `1` :

[image]

How could I center (vertically and horizontally) the number `1` and be able to click anywhere within the yellow zone to activate the checkbox ?

Using `margin: auto;` on the container reduces the label active space and does not achieve what I want :

[image]

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chapo/qd3xs7ut/) containing everything.

Comment: i cant understand plzz be more specific with your question

Comment: Please let me know more about your problem.
You can draw the desired result in the Paint software.

Comment: are the pictures not enough ?

Comment: `How could I center (vertically and horizontally) the number 1 and be able to click anywhere within the yellow zone to activate the checkbox ?` What is unclear please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you have to just modify the CSS properties inside the label tag...

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Hope this is helpful to you

Comment: Thks  -exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have understood you correctly.

Here is your https://jsfiddle.net/3bp4xtvj/16/ with a few changes.

To center the numbers inside the `div` I would recommend you to use `display: flex` with `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;`.

I added a new function and a hidden checkbox inside the first div to give you the idea.

Comment: Thank you. This does the trick but I was hoping to keep my click event on the label as opposed to its container and just expand the "action zone" of the label to its parent. Any way to do that instead ?

Comment: Hey, like Wovi answered before this should work the way you want it:

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```
Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/2gb64895/2/